# Windows 7 'Unidentified Network'

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, internet-connection

So my internet was working last night before I went to bed and woke up to a computer that is showing unidentified network. I have tried multiple ways of fixing it.

```
> route delete 0.0.0.0  
> uninstalling drivers - restart - reinstall from downloaded drivers
> ipconfig /release - /renew 
> static IP 
> speed & duplex from auto negotiation to 1.0gbps full duplex
> and also changed my network address to no value to 1234567890ab
```

(not in that order)

nothing seems to work. I have Comcast internet and when I connect the computer to the modem it works perfectly. but when I connect it to my router again, Unidentified network. I know my router isn't faulty, because my macbook pro, server, NAS, iPhones, and iPads are still working. I have also tried moving the port on the router, still same problem.

my router is a: Cisco Small Business RVS4000
motherboard: GIGABYTE GA-990FXA-UD3

Comment: Have you checked that all of the relevant network-related services are running? You can check which ones should be running at [Black Viper’s site](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-7-service-pack-1-service-configurations/). Off the top of my head, I believe that the *Network Location Awareness* service is critical to this particular issue.

Comment: Check 'Default gateway' on your PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I have Directv and it has a network adaptor that connects into my switch. Well, what happened was it went bad and I'm guessing it was sending out bad packets. I ended up remove the device from the switch and boom, internet is back online. So, I called Directv and they sent me a new box.

Answer (score 0):

I think on cable modems you can't change the device that is connected to the cable modem, without rebooting the cable modem as well. So you can't switch back and forth to test.

Unplug your cable modem's power for 1 minute and then put back your router the way it was.